# Problem in signin method for Actions on Google

Tags: node.js, firebase, actions-on-google

I am trying to use google sign in method for my AoG, to give more customized experience to my user, and will store some data of user so that I can give more relevant answer.I am using dailogflow.After invoking sign in I am getting this error

[image: screenshot of simulator].

```js
app.intent('Default Welcome Intent',(conv)=>{
 
  conv.ask(`HIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII`);
 
});
app.intent('ask_for_sign_in', (conv) => {
  conv.ask(new SignIn(`to get sign in details`));
  
});

app.intent('ask_for_sign_in_confirmation', (conv, params, signin) => {
  if (signin.status !== 'OK') {
    return conv.ask('You need to sign in before using the app.');
  }
  const payload = conv.user.profile.payload
  
    conv.ask(`I got your account details, ${payload.name}. What do you want to do next?`)
  const access = conv.user.access.token;
  
  db.collection("user").doc(access).set({
    name:"name",
    name2 : conv.user.access.name,
  }).then(()=>{
            conv.close(`document successfully written`);
            return;
  }).catch((e)=>{
    conv.close(`error writing document ${e}`);
  })
  // possibly do something with access token
  return conv.ask('Great! Thanks for signing in.');
});
```

Comment: Can you look at the logs to see if there's an error?

Comment: Can you update the question to show how the `ask_for_sign_in` and `ask_for_sign_in_confirmation` intents are configured in Dialogflow? Do you have Dialogflow logging turned on, and what do they indicate? Have you tested this from an actual mobile device, or just through the simulator?

Comment: When you get this error, this means that your fulfillment has failed. Check the logs to get more details about the error.

Answer (score 0):

```js
app.intent('Start Signin', conv => {
  conv.ask(`siging you in`);
  conv.ask(new SignIn('To get your account details'))
})
app.intent('Default Welcome Intent',(conv)=>{
  conv.ask(`hi`);
})
// Create a Dialogflow intent with the `actions_intent_SIGN_IN` event.
app.intent('Get Signin', (conv, params, signin) => {
  if (signin.status === 'OK') {
    const payload = conv.user.profile.payload
    const {email} = conv.user;
    conv.ask(`I got your account details, ${payload.name}.and ${email} What do you want to do next?`)
    db.collection(`user`).doc(email).set({
      name:"some name",
    }).then(()=>{
          conv.ask(`success`);
          return;
    }).catch((e)=>{
        conv.close(`unscess ${e}`);
    })
  } else {
    conv.ask(`I won't be able to save your data, but what do you want to do next?`)
  }
})
```

this code will work perfectly fine , if anyone like me wants to store data of the user so that you can give relevant info when required , it is working on simulator too don't worry, and don't forget to add clientID in dailogflow like `app=dailogflow({debug:true,clientID:"your clientID"})` and to get signIn method from actions on google module `{dailogflow,signIn}=require("actions-on-google")`..

Comment: where you having issue? @sedhalsoni